# How to give a title for a block of R codes denoted by five or more "#", e.x "#####"?

Tags: r, rstudio

Accidentally, I came to know R codes (in .R file) could be separated into blocks by coding the first line of each block as five or more "#", e.x "#####". No other signs allowed. The default title of each block is "(Untitled)". I tried the same way as in R markdown, but failed. An example is shown in the image.

[image]

Is there anyone able to rename the title?

Comment: You only need 4 `#` and can set titles like this: `#### My Title ####` (in one line). At least, this is RStudio behaviour. I'm not sure whether the base client also works like this.

Comment: `# My Title ####` is enough. These are the four terminating `#`'s which generate the block.

Comment: There are other signs allowed. Go to Menu "Code -> Insert section".

Comment: You are right, learned something again. Thank you!

Comment: Both are working. Thank you. Personally, I would prefer using `#### My Title ####` format.